# Delete method is not allowed when calling api endpoint in Django Rest Framework using DestroyModelMixin

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, postman, mixins

I have imported **DestroyModelMixin** in UpdateAPIView so that I can use both PUT and DELETE methods in the same api endpoint. It works for PUT and can be updated, but when I call DELETE in **postman**, it says DELETE is not allowed.

But, when I make a separate view using just DestroyAPIView, it works fine. I want to have a single api for both update and delete.

My models:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cartitems')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name
```

My view:

```
class CartItemUpdateAPIView(UpdateAPIView,mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = CartItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CartItemSerializer

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        instance.delete()
```

My serializer:

```
class CartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['id','cart', 'item', 'quantity']
        depth = 1
```

My urls:

```
path('api/cartitemupdate/<int:pk>', views.CartItemUpdateAPIView.as_view(), name='api-cartitem-update'),
```

Comment: `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` use this Concrete View Classes..It provides get, put, patch and delete method handlers.